# vb.net chart reduce the gap between candlestick

Tags: vb.net, charts, candlestick-chart

i decreased the size of candlestick in vb.net chart with this code

```
 For Each a In Chart1.Series
            a("PointWidth") = "0.25"
 Next
```

the problems now big gap between candlestick,how to decrease it.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4ksb.png)

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clhCy.png)

Comment: Lots of people provide screenshots when they aren't of much use. This is an instance where screenshots could be quite useful.

Comment: thank you for your replay,i added two pictures ,befor ,and now,